# Java programming for minecraft bukkit plugins

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

Hello guys I know there are obviously tutorials out there for learning java, but I was wondering is there any existing tutorials that are aimed at teaching you how to develop bukkit plugins via teaching you java in the same adventure!

This can be in form of a eBook, video or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to learn java before you try to make bukkit plugins. I tried making plugins before I learned java, and it was much harder than I expected. Read [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/&ei=2b31Us2LDoz2oAT-toDwDw&usg=AFQjCNHohD0Cv4ea4bkZEjS1UWkOviLTAQ&sig2=aZ5Xix4HBeDiyAbTs9QriA), and get a basic understanding of java before you start. Also java books are a great resource. Once you learn java, Pogostick29Dev and SGTCaze (Youtube channels) are a perfect place to start making Bukkit plugins.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I learned to code Bukkit plugins  (It would be  *very* helpful if you had a basic understanding of things like loops and if statements in other languages)

---

To learn java, theres a nice [YouTube tutorial by TheNewBoston](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28). It is for beginners, I watched only the first 20 episodes.

Then, you could take a look at [`Bukkit's` official plugin tutorial](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial).

After that, you should just Google what you don't know, and use the [Bukkit forums](http://bukkit.org/forums/) under [`Plugin Development`](http://bukkit.org/forums/plugin-development.5/) or the [Spigot forums](http://www.spigotmc.org/forums/) under [`Plugin Development`](http://www.spigotmc.org/forums/spigot-plugin-development.52/), as questions on `Bukkit` get more attention there then they do here. If you have only `Java` questions, or any other code-related questions, then this is definitely the place to go.

If you have no understanding in coding at **ALL**, I recommend you take a couple tutorials at [CodeAcademy](http://www.codeacademy.com) on `JavaScript`, as it's one of the most simple and easy to learn programing languages (in my opinion), and it's the first language I learned.

Just remember, though, `JavaScript` is a different thing than `Java`, so you obviously won't learn Java at [CodeAcademy](http://www.codeacademy.com), yet, if you take the [`JavaScript` tutorial](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript), it will give you a basic understanding of things like `if statements`, `for loops`, `while loops`, and `switch statements`.

Answer (score 1):

All tutorials i've seen for minecraft assume that you have some basic java skills. As most minecraft tutorials will only show you how to use the API, not how to write java code. So i would suggest to start with a basic java tutorial, and try to implement that into a minecraft plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get basic Java down, http://www.youtube.com/user/PogoStick29Dev has some pretty sweet tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial

It worked quite well for me!

Comment: Yes, but i wonder if that teaches you java or requires you to have past experience in java.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at bukkit's plugin tutorial at:

http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial

Almost everything you need is there!